# Can an Xbox One player party or voice chat with an Xbox 360 player?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, xbox-one

I have an Xbox one and my brother has an Xbox 360.  I couldn't figure out how to join his party or invite him to mine, or even initiate a private chat.  Is this possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't voice chat between Xbox One and 360. There was a Q&A session with Microsoft on [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/08/05/ask-microsoft-anything-about-xbox-one) in August when this was confirmed:

> Is there cross-console Party Chat? i.e. since it’s all “Xbox Live,”
>   can people on Xbox 360s Party Chat with their friends on Xbox One?
>
> WHITTEN: For a variety of technical reasons – including the sound
>   quality that I talk about below – we don’t support voice chat between
>   the two systems. You will still be able to send and receive text
>   messages to friends on both systems, however.

This doesn't say anything about joining parties across consoles, however given that cross-console voice chat doesn't work I wouldn't expect to be able to join parties across consoles either.

You can send text messages across consoles, however.