# VOIP on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, voice-chat

I found most question on Xbox on this site, sorry if it belongs to superuser.

I plan to buy Xbox 360 with Kinect. I wonder if I can use it for telephony as well. Skype is not supported. Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use voice chat on XBOX 360. But **you can't use it as a telephone device.**

Note* It only works when communicating with another XBOX 360. You can't even chat with an XBOX one as you can see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149166/can-an-xbox-one-player-party-or-voice-chat-with-an-xbox-360-player), and in the comment of claus.

Plug the headset  in your controller and create a party on Xbox live to voice chat with your friends.

Comment: Does it support external calls? E.g. accept call from mobile network?

Comment: @LeosLiterak Sadly not one that I know off.

Comment: This answer is misleading as the original question is clearly asking about VOIP.  The only xbox 360 to xbox 360 voice chat are supported. You can't even chat with xbox one users.  The xbox 360 is not a telephony solution.

Comment: @Claus I edited the answer, it is (more) correct now.

Comment: Thank you. It is pity, hardware must be capable for such feature. I would pay for such application instead of buying Siemens Gigaset VOIP phone.